# tar: how to bundle the "extract to directory XXX" info inside a tar file

Tags: shell, tar

I know 'tar xf -C DIR' will untar the files in DIR, but is there an option to bundle the "-C DIR" information within the tarball when I create the tar file, so that when I use 'tar xf' the files will be automatically extracted into DIR?

Thanks.

Comment: Tar the directory you want. Mkdir DIR, mv the files into it, then tar cvpPf file.tar DIR.

Comment: How can I avoid mkdir-ing DIR? Actually the files to be tarred are distributed in different locations, and I want to add them to the tarball by specifying their pathnames instead of copying all of them to DIR and then later removing them. Is there an option to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create DIR, then **symlink** the files into DIR (no copying involved), then use GNU tar with the dereference (-h) option:

```
mkdir DIR
ln -s /path/to/f1 /path2/f2 DIR/
tar chf archive.tar DIR
rm -rf DIR
```

This will archive the actual files pointed by the symlinks (and not the symlinks you created temporarily)

Downside is you can't put actual symlinks in the archive, of course (they too will be dereferenced)

Comment: I've noticed looking at your profile that you seem to be unaware you're supposed to accept answers that work for you. That actually works somewhat better than "thanks" :)

Comment: Oh... I didn't know that. I just did it. Thanks again. :)