# How to add specific directory for a file during tar file generation?

Tags: tar

When I create .tar file using tar command in UNIX, what tar command option I need to use for adding specific directories hierarchy which does not exist for the file.

For example:

```
Test_File.tar
L MAIN
  L SUB1
    L Process.txt
```

But, the MAIN and SUB1 directories doesn't exist and should be added only in the tar file.

Comment: you have read all of `man tar` or http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tar and found nothing to help you ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok here is my answer based on [this related one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20053716/6622232)!

1. Let's do this example in /var/tmp/example

   `mkdir -p /var/tmp/example && cd "$_"`
2. Create our file Process.txt

   `echo "Hello" > Process.txt`
3. Create our temporary folder structure following your example.

   `mkdir -p MAIN/SUB1`
4. Makes a symlink from our file and put it into the temporary folder structures. (to avoid to copy the file)

   `ln -s $(readlink -f Process.txt) MAIN/SUB1/`
5. Create our archive with the ['h' tar option](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/dereference.html) to 'dereference' the symlinks !

   `tar -chf archive.tar MAIN`

Comment: Great idea to make desired folder structure without copying. And `-h` brilliant! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply specify the full path to it starting from the current directory:

```
tar -cpf file.tar MAIN/SUB1/Process.txt
```

Comment: The MAIN and SUB1 directories doesn't exist and they need to be added only in tar file.

Comment: @SyS Are you only trying to update your tar file? Or are you creating a new one? You should just create a temporary directory structure containing copies of those files instead.